# Как получить значение из столбца последней строки таблицы?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Как получить значение из столбца последней строки таблицы?

Есть таблица, в каждой строке которой есть `id` и `sum` числа.

Как получить `id` из последней строки таблицы, то есть строки с максимальным `id`?

Comment: в базах данных нет понятия первой/последней строки - все зависит от сортировки по полю/полям. Можно выбрать например строку с максимальным ID...

Comment: да, мне это и нужно)

Comment: Вот посмотрите, ваш вопрос как оказывается: _Как получить максимальный id из таблицы?_, а что вы написали в трёх предложениях.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получить максимальное ID:

```
select max(id) from table_name;
```

Получить всю строку с максимальным ID:

```
select * from table_name order by id desc limit 1;
```